# Populate the first column of the table with array items - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am new to coding and trying to write a function that would generate a table with 3 columns and with the number of rows equal to the number of indexes in an array. This is the array and the code I'm using to generate the table

```
var msg1Arr = ['loginCommand', 'version', 'xID', 'passcode', 'machineID', 'equipSN', 'userSlot', 'clubID', 'loginType'];

function generateTable(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    for(var i=0; i<realArray.length; i++){ //columns
        var row=document.createElement("tr");

        for (var j=0; j < 3; j++){  //rows
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            var cellText = document.createTextNode("t");
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    body.appendChild(tbl); 
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
};
```

However, this code fills in all cells with "t" string. I need the array to populate the first column, one index per row. Please help!

Comment: `var cellText = document.createTextNode("t");` <= Why would your code be putting a "t" in the cell I wonder?

Comment: Also if you only want to pre-load the first cell per row, you only need to set the text if `j === 0`

Comment: Side note that `var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];` can be replaced with just `document.body`

Comment: Are you looking to create three table data columns per table row and have the first TD column populate the value of the array?

Comment: So per your example you would have 9 rows as your array has 9 values, then have the value of the array populated in the first table data column?

Comment: Date Landry, that's correct.

Comment: Taplar, that did it for me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order the first column to be populated with the arrays elements.
Modify the code to be

```
var msg1Arr = ['loginCommand', 'version', 'xID', 'passcode', 'machineID', 'equipSN', 'userSlot', 'clubID', 'loginType'];
    
    function generateTable(){
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var tbl = document.createElement("table");
        var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    
        for(var i=0; i<msg1Arr.length; i++){ //columns
            var row=document.createElement("tr");
    
            for (var j=0; j < 3; j++){  //rows
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText = document.createTextNode("t");
                if(j == 0){
                   cellText = document.createTextNode(msg1Arr[i]);
                }
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
        }
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        body.appendChild(tbl); 
        tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `"t"` with `realArray[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a forEach loop on the array which will iterate with each value within the array. Set your value and index in the forEach function `v` , `i`... Insert the row with each iteration of the forEach loop, then set a for loop to create your table data columns that will reside within the rows. You said three, so the for loop can be hard coded to create a TD each time you loop through the for loop. Lastly to set the first column tot he value within the array, use a conditional that checks if the iterator is set to `1`, if it is then set the textContent of that TD to the value with in the array...

See the comments in the code for further explanation.

```js
var msg1Arr = ['loginCommand', 'version', 'xID', 'passcode', 'machineID', 'equipSN', 'userSlot', 'clubID', 'loginType'];

function generateTable() {
  // get the parent element here i used a div 'container'
  let cont = document.getElementById("container");
  // create the table element
  let table = document.createElement("TABLE");
  // use forEach on the array to loop through each iteration of values in the array
  msg1Arr.forEach(function(v, i) {
    // append the parent element (display) element with the table
    cont.append(table);
    // each iteration through the array, insert a table row into the table element
    // we use the index of the foreach loop to insert a table row
    let tr = table.insertRow(i);
    // iterate through the desired amount of columns using a for loop
    for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
      // each iteration of the for loop, create a table data 
      let td = document.createElement('TD');
      // append the row with the newly created TD
      tr.append(td);
      // conditional to see if the index of the td's is the first iteration of the TD's
      // if it is, then we insert the value within the array into that table data column
      if (j === 1) {
        td.textContent = v;
      }
    }
    // set your attributed for the border in the table
    table.setAttribute("border", "2");
    // append the table row to the table
    table.append(tr);
  })
};
// run the function
generateTable();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!--write a function that would generate a table with 3 columns and with the number of rows equal to the number of indexes in an array.-->
</div>
```